# How to download a word docx file that is stored in SQL from API in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, download, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi have a word document that is saved as a varbinary in sql
I am trying to download this file by converting back into bytes and then a stream
I am however getting an error that reads "ERROR Http failure during parsing"

This is my code below

```
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadFileFromDataBase(int testId, int studentId)
    {
                 
                var answerSheetBytes = await _testRepository.GetUserAnswerFileAsync(studentId, testId);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(answerSheetBytes);
                return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
   }

public async Task<byte[]> GetUserAnswerFileAsync(int studentId,int testId)
        {
            var docs = await GetUserAnswerDocumentAsync(studentId, testId);
            var doc = docs?.FirstOrDefault();

            if (doc?.TestDocument is null) //throw new Exception("No document found");
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] bytes;
                    bytes = new byte[0];
                    return bytes;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
            return doc.TestDocument;
        }
```

Comment: why dont you save  it in a blob like azure storage or something?

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify your approach by returning a file instead of a stream. If you need to optimize memory usage then revisit it to use streams, but I wouldn't assume that would be a requirement with Word files, unless you expect them to be very large.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadFileFromDataBase(int testId, int studentId)
{ 
            var answerSheetBytes = await _testRepository.GetUserAnswerFileAsync(studentId, testId);
            return File(_testRepository.GetUserAnswerFileAsync(studentId, testId), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "MyDocument.docx");
}
```